# Are there any download managers for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download-manager

Please suggest a download manager compatible with Chrome if any exist.

Answer (score 3):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/board/viewtopic.php?t=10815) integrates with Google Chrome, catches downloads and is [FOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSS)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Chrome plugin called [Download Helper (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mfjkgbjaikamkkojmakjclmkianficch).

This extension allows you to download links on a web page with FlashGet, FlashGet Mini, Thunder, Mini Thunder, QQ Whirlwind, eMule, Orbit, Internet Download Manager and Free Download Manager.

Answer (score 1):

[Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) it's compatible with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Download Accelerator Manager, but here is also a [link](http://www.chromeplugins.org/chrome/list-of-download-managers-for-google-chrome/) to a couple you can choose from.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to go to `chrome://flags/` and enable `chrome://flags/#enable-download-resumption` (simply copy paste to chrome) this should allow to resume downloads when they get interrupted - no need for downloader in the first place.