# A better Chrome download manager plugin

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, download-manager

So, it's really frustrating when I'm downloading a really large file, and it gets cut off halfway through due to either my internet, or the host's internet. For instance, there was a file one time that Chrome was literally incapable of downloading since it would never finish before it lost connection for half a second. So, I got Flashget, which works great, but it doesn't always work for everything (occasionally sites discourage use of dl managers; it's also at times hard to get the link for downloads; etc.).

So, I'm wondering, **is there a Chrome plugin download manager that will not fail a download?**

Comment: If your internet goes out then the download will fail.

Comment: Flashget restores a download by picking up where it left off. Chrome is capable of having the same thing, but it doesn't.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of this already existing question http://superuser.com/questions/243054/are-there-any-download-managers-for-google-chrome?rq=1

Comment: You might want to got to chrome://flags/ and enable chrome://flags/#enable-download-resumption this should automagicaly  resume downloads when then get interrupted - no need for downloader in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet download Manager is a good downloading Heavy/Stacked. Whenever my Internet cuts off during a Long download. It continues from where it left off.

It also has an extension called the [IDM Integration Module](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/register/new_faq/chrome_extension.html) this extension will be automatically enabled after you download Internet Download Manager

You can download IDM just by typing it on Google and you can easily get the results. Well considering on some sites blocking or discouragement DL Managers. I have never encountered any of them when I am using IDM.

Answer (score 0):

I got frustrated with Chromes inability to handle larger downloads too, and ended up finding [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) to be a good solution.

Free Download Manager is a free and open source program for Windows, and has an impressive [feature list](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm). While it supports download accelerating and download resuming like many download managers, it can do a lot more like torrenting, scheduling, ZIP previewing.

Free Download Manager can integrate itself with your browser (whether it be Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari, etc), or you can get a third-party plugin to integrate it, like [Downloaders for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloaders/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj) or [Flashgot for Firefox](http://flashgot.net/).

There are two things that need noting though:

- Download resuming has to be allowed by the server serving the downloads, or even Free Download Manager cannot revive the download after a lost Internet connection.
- Free Download Manager still won't necessarily work for everything, especially on sites where they are trying to prevent you from using a download accelerator.